# How to save and restore unicode string from SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, unicode

I want to save in my DB unicode strings

i.e. "Content" below. How can I do this?

```
using (DbCommand objCMD = objDB.GetStoredProcCommand("usp_InsertMessage"))
{
    objDB.AddInParameter(objCMD, "@Author", DbType.String, msg.Author);
    objDB.AddInParameter(objCMD, "@Email", DbType.String, msg.Email);
    objDB.AddInParameter(objCMD, "@Content", DbType.String, msg.Content);
    objDB.AddInParameter(objCMD, "@Guid", DbType.Guid, msg.Guid);

    try
    {
        objDB.ExecuteNonQuery(objCMD);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since .NET uses Unicode for all its strings, this *should* be fine, **IF** your parameters like `@Author` and `@Email` are defined as `NVARCHAR(x)` in your stored procedure, and if the columns you store that information into are also defined as `NVARCHAR(x)`.

So question is: are you seeing any problems?? If so: **what are they**??

As a sidenote: I would **always** define/specify a **length** for a string parameter. Not sure what that `AddInParameter` method does if you omit the length of the string parameter - often there will be a default, which may or may not be sufficient for you; so to avoid any unexpected surprises, I prefer to always explicitly define a max length for any string parameters.